# How to know what parameters to fill out for a webform using a python 3.0 script

Tags: python

I'm going to test this on gmail just because it's a simple platform that a lot of people have and will know how to use. Please enlighten me if a) my code is wrong and b) what are the parameter inputs that are required for the webform.

My code is currently:

```
data = {'Email':"Emailtypedhere",'Passwd':"Passwordtypedhere"} 

#note that I use 'Email' and 'Passwd' based on the name= of the username/password form fields. 
#if I should be using it based on the id= please advise. Thanks!

url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"
data_in_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
data_in_bytes = data_in_string.encode('utf-8')
urllib.request.urlopen(url,data_in_bytes)
```

From that I would assume that I am now logged into gmail. Is that correct? I got the URL from the `action` type in the form and `Passwd` from the label form password and the `Email` from the Email label form.

Here is the code from Gmail, specifically for the form. Please let me know if there are any parameters I am missing or if my code is valid. Thanks!

```
<form novalidate="" id="gaia_loginform" action="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="continue" id="continue" value="https://mail.google.com/mail/">
<input type="hidden" name="service" id="service" value="mail">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" id="rm" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="dsh" id="dsh" value="-6956126811101026847">
<input type="hidden" name="ltmpl" id="ltmpl" value="default">
<input type="hidden" name="hl" id="hl" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="scc" id="scc" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="ss" id="ss" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="q83s3oZvHfE">
<input type="hidden" id="pstMsg" name="pstMsg" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="dnConn" name="dnConn" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="checkConnection" name="checkConnection" value="youtube:377:1">
<input type="hidden" id="checkedDomains" name="checkedDomains" value="youtube">
<input type="hidden" name="timeStmp" id="timeStmp" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="secTok" id="secTok" value="">
<div class="email-div">
<label for="Email"><strong class="email-label">Username</strong></label>
<input type="email" spellcheck="false" name="Email" id="Email" value="">
</div>
<div class="passwd-div">
<label for="Passwd"><strong class="passwd-label">Password</strong></label>
<input type="password" name="Passwd" id="Passwd">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="g-button g-button-submit" name="signIn" id="signIn" value="Sign in">
<label class="remember" onclick="">
<input type="checkbox" name="PersistentCookie" id="PersistentCookie" value="yes">
<strong class="remember-label">
Stay signed in
</strong>
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="rmShown" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You picked an interesting choice to start with :) It sounds like your purpose is solely to figure out which elements you need to submit for a given form (rather than 'How do I log in to Gmail?', which would use a completely different process). The short (and admittedly uneducated) answer is that the 'real' checks are done on the server side, so there is no requirement for there to be an indication on the client side (although [HTML5 seems to provide a way](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp)). Therefore you can't say with certainty which will be required just by looking at the form.

As for your example, I messed around with logging into Gmail in this way a while back, and I remember needing to use the `GALX` and `dsh` values (two internal Gmail variables) provided in the form. So your arguments would need to be:

```
data = {
    'Email': 'email', 
    'Passwd': 'passwrd', 
    'GALX': 'GALX_value_above', 
    'dsh': 'dsh_value_above' }
```

You would then encode the arguments and open the URL. There is probably a better method of determining the required values, but I recall testing combinations until I was able to access with just those that were required. Again, if you are trying to log in to Gmail then this is **not** the way, but you made it clear this is just an example, so I guess no warning necessary :)

Comment: You're correct, I just chose Gmail arbitrarily. What is GALX and what is dsh? Why did you choose those 2 input types? Is it because the value suggests that it is a key of some sort?

Comment: Note that in order for me to submit a form on the webpage I'm testing on (it's an internal work one so I can't post code here about it), there are no GALX or dsh values. If I were to put all the input types into the data dictionary would that work as well?

Comment: Actually (and somebody much wiser than I am will correctly me), I believe all checking is done server-side, meaning that Gmail needs those two values at a minimum in order to proceed but provides no way of knowing it on the client side. As how I chose them, I believe I started from just username and password and worked my way up to those values. Again, this is dependent on the server-side code and you couldn't intuit it from the form (but it looks like HTML will have a `required` tag http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp).

Comment: @Chowza Right, if you accounted for all the values then it should work (depends on the values, etc.). Give it a whirl and if not we can try to troubleshoot.

Comment: No prob at all, I remember wrestling with that same question. Good luck!